# Debian sendmail not sending to gmail

Tags: debian, sendmail

i want to use the command `sendmail` to send mails. It usually works -> I can send mails to my email (@icloud.com) and it works without any problems. But if I want to send to a @gmail address, it doesn't worl. There is no error message or something like that, ist just the email wich does not reach the email adress.
What can I do? Or what could be the problem?

I got a Message from Mail Delivery Subsystem this time:

```
The original message was received at Mon, 18 Sep 2023 08:23:16 +0200
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
< (The mail address @gmail) >
(reason: 550-5.7.1 [ (IPv6) ] Our system has detected that)

----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
DATA
<<< 550-5.7.1 [ (IPv6 Address) ] Our system has detected that
<<< 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR
<<< 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please review
<<< 550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information
<<< 550 5.7.1 . ck9-20020a170906c44900b0099de8722195si7349253ejb.747 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

And:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; WS301.WS301.intern
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 08:23:16 +0200

Final-Recipient: RFC822;(@gmail.com address)
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 [ (IPv6) ] Our system has detected that
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 08:23:17 +0200
```

Comment: So attach a **successful** log message that proves the gmail server accepted the example mail from yours, but didn't delivered it further.

Comment: Have you received "bounce" emails? [Notifications about delivery problems] Typical SMTP server configuration sends first "warning" email after **4 hours** and "final failure" email after **5 days**.

Comment: Oh well, i actually got at this time a Email from Mail Delivery Subsystem. Wi will put the Output in my Question

Comment: "There is no error message" - I see an unusually precise and helpful error message in the logs you posted. Did you check your PTR records?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty specific:

> Our system has detected that this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and authentication. Please review https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information

Following the link gives a lot of generally sensible advice. The specifics for Gmail, however, start in the section "Follow recommended email server practices
":

- Your sending IP address must have a PTR record. PTR records verify that the sending hostname is associated with the sending IP address. Every IP address must map to a hostname in the PTR record. The hostname specified in the PTR record must have a forward DNS that refers to the sending IP address.
- An IPv6 authorization error could mean that the PTR record for the sending server isn’t using IPv6. If you use an email service provider, confirm they’re using an IPv6 PTR record.
- If you’re still having mail delivery problems after following the guidelines in this article, try [Troubleshooting for senders with email delivery issues](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2696779).

In turn, following through there leads to this statement from Google,

- Sign messages with [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/). Gmail doesn't authenticate messages signed with keys that use fewer than 1024 bits.
- Publish a [SPF Record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786).
- Publish a [DMARC policy](https://dmarc.org/)